# É possível colocar um animation no pie chart

Tags: animação, google-charts

É possível utilizar alguma animation no pie-chart do google? Coloquei dessa forma, mas não está funcionando:

```
var options = {
            title: 'Tickets por prazo',
            series: {
                0: {"color": '#57c8f2'},
                1: {"color": '#ff6c60'}
            },
            animation:{
                duration: 1500,
                startup: true
            }
        };
```

Se puderem ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue destacar as informações:

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Tarefas', 'Horas por dia'],
      ['Trabalho', 11],
      ['Comida', 2],
      ['Comunitário', 2],
      ['TV', 2],
      ['Dormir', 7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Atividades',          
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var counter = 0;

    var handler = setInterval(function(){ 
        counter = counter + 0.1
        options = {
          title: 'Atividades',           
          slices: { 1: {offset: counter},                       
                    3: {offset: counter},                       
                    5: {offset: counter},
          }
        };
        chart.draw(data, options);

        if (counter > 0.3) clearInterval(handler);
    }, 200);        
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vucxqdn/3/)

Essa "animação" é chamada de *Exploding a Slice*

Sugiro que dê uma olhada na documentação: [Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart).

Comment: Olá amiga, na realidade o que eu gostaria era uma animation, por exemplo, você vê o gráfico se montando, algo do tipo.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold, entendi o que você quer. Fiz um update no código que mostra a animação se destacando, antes do Exploding.

Comment: Entendi, fiz com outros valores, mas do mesmo jeito que você falou, muito obrigado.